# A short and neat little riddle

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> I'm the sharpest blade, dripped in blood
>
> Laughter I reaped, and suffering I brought
>
> I'm wielded by the devil in his hall of marble,
>
> who's weeping amidst a pile of rubble

What am I?

> Hint: The riddle is metaphorical

> Hint2: The answer is a human organ

Comment: Hi, welcome to Puzzling! Did you create this riddle?

Comment: I create this by myself

Comment: Naively, I can come up with rot13(n fplgur) but it doesn't match a lot of the clues.

Comment: It might be worth considering adding a hint to the riddle.

Comment: Hints are added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is:

> TONGUE

I'm the sharpest blade, dripped in blood

> "The tongue is mightier than the sword".  "Thoughtless words cut like a sword".

Laughter I reaped, and suffering I brought

> Words can evoke laughter and suffering.

I'm wielded by the devil in his hall of marble,

> Silver-tongued devil, hall of marble = teeth.

who's weeping amidst a pile of rubble

> Not sure about this clue, but weeping could be salivating and the rubble could be chewed up food.

Comment: Nice! The weeping part is just a little addition that verbal abuse hurts both the sender and receiver